# Filling Javascript array with objects properties from database

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Hi I'm trying to make an array " events" in javascript that is filled with objects of two properties {Title: , Date:}

But, the value of those two properties is brought from the database using PHP!

Here's my code but I don't know why it doesn't work..

```
var events = [ 
    <?php 



//Connect to mysql server
//Select database

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count>0){
    for($i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++){
    $row= mysql_fetch_row($result);

    echo "{ Title: ".$row['title'].", Date: ".$row['date']." },";
        }

    $row= mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo "{ Title: ".$row['title'].", Date: ".$row['date']." }";

    }
    ?>];
```

Comment: `json_encode()` would make this much easier.

Comment: This code is wrong on so many levels that it's hard to describe exactly how. Take a step back and try one thing at a time.

Comment: @alex Sorry but where should it be?

Comment: Do you really mean the following:

    $i<$count-1

If $count is 1, you won't get any results.

Comment: @Jon I'm a beginner and I'm trying to collect things together. I'll try again. :(

Comment: @user1884047 there's another echo after the loop. This is because I don't want " , " for the last object.

Comment: @Lamia: Try to focus on doing one thing well and after you 've nailed it bring in another. What you want to do can be written in one line of code: `json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query(...)))`, but you won't reach this solution by trying to juggle multiple things you are not familiar with at the same time.

Comment: @Jon the problem is I need to use objects in the array :( I'll see what I can do. Thank you Jon.

Comment: @Lamia: What exactly is stopping you from using objects? [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) has a second optional parameter that works fine for this. As I said, learn one thing well and *then* bring in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first take the building of your results:

Use array_push to create your data from your SQL (this is called an [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
var events = 
<?php 
  $json = array();
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $row= mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $item = array();
    $item['Title'] = $row['title'];
    $item['Date'] = $row['date'];
    $json[] = $item;
  }
```

Now echo the results as JSON using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
  echo json_encode($json);
?>;
```

Tested in PHP 5.3.2

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. 
It only works with this     var events = [ 
    { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("02/13/2011") }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("02/25/2011") }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("12/01/2012") }
];
but when I try php nothing happens :(

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON you want it to return?

Comment: like this ? `var events = [ { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("02/13/2011") }]` Title and Date are retrieved from database.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that part, maybe I'm having trouble understanding where your code was breaking. Are you having trouble before you get to the encode part?  Your question title suggests that you are having trouble encoding an array into JavaScript

Comment: can you look at the /var/log/apache/error.log it will have the last PHP error at the bottom

Comment: Sorry but I thought the error was related with the arrays. 
nothing in the document, it only has old errors I've fixed before. Which means PHP is working correctly. but maybe the other part of javascript, where I use the 'events array' has the problem there.